# Question on Galois extension of field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, galois-theory, integral-domain

I would like to ask if the following is true:

> Suppose we have an integral domain $A$ and a group action $G$ on $A$. We consider $A^{G}$ the subring of $A$ fixed by $G$. Let $L$ be the field of fractions of $A^{G}$ and $K$ the field of fractions of $A.$ Can we safely say that $K$ is a Galois extension of $L$ and if so, can we say that $A$ is a free $A^{G}$ module?

Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not true that $A$ will be $A^G$-free all the time. Take a Galois extension of number fields $K/L$ such that the ring of integers of $K$ is not free over the ring of integers of $L$ (these exist with, e.g., $L/\mathbf{Q}$ imaginary quadratic), and then take $G$ to be the Galois group of $K$ over $L$.

Comment: Do you know of any other conditions needed for this to happen? (Like say A is a noetherian, regular local rings etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer only: Let $K$ be a field and $G$ be a finite group. Then the extension $K/K^G$ is Galois.

Proof: for every $x\in K$ the orbit $Gx$ of $x$ under $G$ is invariant under $G$. The coefficients of the separable polynomial

$
f_x:=\prod\limits_{a\in Gx} (X-a)
$

thus are in $K^G$. One concludes that $K/K^G$ is separable algebraic.

Now let $g\in K^G[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial having $x\in K$ as a root. Then all elements of $Gx$ are roots of $g$. Hence $f_x$ divides $g$, that is $g=f_x$, which shows that $g$ splits completely in $K$. Consequently $K/K^G$ is normal.

The argument also shows that the ring extension $A/A^G$ is integral.

The assertion is wrong if $G$ is infinite: let $k$ be an infinite field and let $G$ be the group of all $k$-automorphisms $g$ of the rational function field $K:=k(X)$ with the property $g(X)=\frac{aX+b}{cX+d}$. Then $k(X)^G=k$.

A rather simple case in which freeness holds: let $A$ be a 1-dimensional, noetherian, integrally closed domain and assume that $A^G$ is local. Then $A/A^G$ is free.

Proof: $A^G$ is 1-dimensional; by the Lying-over-Theorem there exists a maximal ideal $M$ of $A$ lying over the maximal ideal of $A^G$. By assumption $A_M$ is a discrete valuation ring.

One always has $A\cap K^G = A^G$. Consequently $A_M\cap K^G=A^G$, hence $A^G$ is a discrete valuation ring.

Moreover $A^G$ is integrally closed, that is $A$ is the integral closure of $A^G$ in the Galois extension $K/K^G$, thus $A/A^G$ is finite.

Finitely generated, torsion-free modules over a discrete valution ring are free.

Note that one can check locality of $A^G$ in $A$ itself: $G$ acts on the maximal ideals of $A$, and $A^G$ is local iff all maximal ideals lie in the same orbit.

In general in my opinion the problem of freeness seems to be difficult: several things can go wrong. If $A/A^G$ is free it must have rank equal to $|G|$ -- in particular the ring extension must be finite. It is difficult to ensure this without assumptions about noetherianity of $A^G$. But it seems that $A$ noetherian does not  imply that $A^G$ is noetherian. And even in the noetherian and finite case, moreover assuming that $A$ is integrally closed, the extension $A/A^G$ is usually not free.